# a line is drown over alertDialog.setButton in MainActivity.java

Tags: android

I am doing alert dialog demo. It work fine but I found a line over "setButton" in MainActivity.java file. Hear is my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Creating alert Dialog with one Button

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this).create();

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("Welcome to AndroidHive.info");

            // Setting Icon to Dialog

            // I got line hear........ over setButtob .........
            alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                            // closed
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();![enter image description here][1]

        }
    });`
```

You cab see the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykdak.png) and get more idea of what I mean to say.

Answer (score 2):

You mean you got a warning saying the method is deprecated?

That's because setButton is not used anymore, it's deprecated, instead you should be doing something like this:

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
    // blablabla
}
});
```

Also notice you can get the String "OK" like thing as well : android.R.string.ok , which is the recommended way ;)

Answer (score 1):

I went through the [url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykdak.png) image, which made your question clear. This is showing because that method( setButton) is depreciated. You are using

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
```

at the top. This prevents is from giving the warning message and you cannot read the warning message( which probably is that: This method has been depreciated). If you remove the top line, then it will tell you why it shows cross line over setButton. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setButton%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.os.Message%29). It says that this method was depreciated in API level 3.

For seeing how use use it in proper way, you can go through this official documentation page of using [Alert Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). You can also see the tutorial [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1513).